# jQueryUI droppable and sortable - cant change the order and few bugs i cant fix

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have put most of the code together, just cant get few things working: -

1. Items in the "Selected DVD's" area I need to be able to change the order of these DVDs in this list only, so i can change the order from 1,2,3 to 3,1,2.
2. Items in the "Un-selected" area wont drag up into the selected dvds area
3. If i click on the link at the top "add all unselected dvd's" and then click on the link "Remove all selected dvds" it doesnt add them into the correct area at the bottom. However if you click the "Remove all selected dvds" link first... it works
4. Following #3 if i then add a new dvd at the top right, sometimes it adds loads of the same dvd?

Here is a working demo of what i have so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/BFWzS/1/

There is more code in the fiddle above ^

```
// let the gallery items be draggable
$( "li", $gallery ).draggable({
  cancel: "a.ui-icon", // clicking an icon won't initiate dragging
  revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
  containment: "document",
  helper: "clone",
  cursor: "move"
});

// let the trash be droppable, accepting the gallery items
$trash.droppable({
  accept: "#gallery > li",
  activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    deleteImage( ui.draggable );
  }
});
```

Hope someone can help us out,

Cheers

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for SO. If you have 4 different problems, then you have four different questions. You have to remember, Stack Overflow is not a place where people fix _your_ code, its a place where people help solves problems that might also help other future visitors

Comment: so all the code there would not currently help other members? I think it would! And the purpose of here is to help people - im stuck - i need a bit of help. If your not going to, dont bother replying!

Comment: No, I don't think *all* your broken code will help other members. Besides, I am helping, I'm giving you tips on how to get answers to your problems

Comment: So it would be more beneficial to do 4 separate posts? Forget it, doesn't matter, thanks for your reply anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As my comments have suggested, you should break this down into more specific problems and ask them as separate questions. But here is some information to help you out:

1. Check out [JQuery Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/)
2. Check out the [Connect Lists option](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists) **[EDIT]** In your JSFIddle, your problem doesn't exist for me (in Chrome)
3. This should be a separate question (although you can probably find a duplicate of this already)
4. If not solved by your answer to 3, then should be an additional question

---

For the purposes of a more meaningful answer, here is some sample code showing the use of JQuery Sortable:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">Selected DVDs</div>
    <ul id="gallery" class="dvdlist">
        <li>DVD 1</li>
        <li>DVD 2</li>
        <li>DVD 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">Un-selected DVDs</div>
    <ul id="trash" class="dvdlist">
        <li>DVD 4</li>
        <li>DVD 5</li>
        <li>DVD 6</li>
    </ul>
</div>

$("#gallery").sortable({
    connectWith: "#trash"
});
$("#trash").sortable({
    connectWith: "#gallery"
});
```

[You can see this in action here.](http://jsfiddle.net/w3vvL/)

Comment: Think my only fault is asking 4 questions in one post, although since its all kind of related i thought this would be ok. 1. Can sortable work with dragable and dropable? This is what im basing the code off http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager. 2. Items in the unselected area if you click, hold and try to drag up into the selected area - it wont drag up? thanks for still trying to help

Comment: Sortable will definitely work for your needs. I have done something fairly similar a few times. Ill see if I can improve your fiddle somehow

Comment: the sortable option doesnt seem to work in the fiddle when i add <div id="sortable gallery"> needs to be able to drag from selected and unselected area and also change order within the div

Comment: thanks for that, ill keep plugging away in the meantime and if you manage anything that would be great, thanks

Comment: @John: Here is a little sample to show you how simple it can be, you will need to extend it for you extra functionality, but the options you use for draggable should still work on sortable: http://jsfiddle.net/w3vvL/

Comment: wow, so much less code! So I just need to add in the nice fade and transition effects and the icons to also add / remove dvds. Im new to jQuery and all the code used in the fiddle i posted seems way over the top. Whats the difference! thanks so much :-)